# Delay Calendly script to reduce render blocking (Google Page Speed Insights)

Tags: performance, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, calendly

I've hit a problem with the Calendly booking script on a client's site.

It's adding some significant time to the page load speed.

I've tried to delay the script by using the below which I grabbed from a fix from a similar question. It doesn't appear to have helped and, to be honest, I don't know anywhere near enough yet to even know if it's working in the first place.

```
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 window.setTimeout(function () { 
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js';
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
 }, 5000);
};
</script>
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" style="min-width: 320px; height: 600px;" data-url="https://calendly.com/markorangerocket/15-minute-meeting"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

If anyone has dealt with this issue before and has a fix for it, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little stale, but posting in case anyone in the future comes across this. The idea behind creating a script dynamically is moving the script addition and evaluation after page load to prevent render-blocking. You will want to remove the script on line 13 and let it be created via the `<script>` at the top of your code that contains the `document.createElement('script')`. I removed the `timeout` function so it will execute immediately after `window.onload`. Example script below

```html
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<script async>
window.onload = function() {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js';
  document.querySelector('.calendly-inline-widget').appendChild(script);
};
</script>
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" style="min-width: 320px; height: 600px;" data-url="https://calendly.com/markorangerocket/15-minute-meeting"></div>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

Comment: Calendly ships with async script already. 

`<script type="text/javascript" src=https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js async></script>` 

The real problem is the boat-load of scripts it ships with – 8 scripts and 2 css files. My page scores a 99% without it and 54% with it. I personally wouldn't use this bloatware.